# How to get the ID of the max counted user in Order table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with

```
orderNumber(pk) , customerNumber , comment
```

I have to count the maximum order placed by a user and show its user ID and MAX count . I have following Query

It shows the count Right but it takes the first CustomerNumber in the table

```
SELECT maxCount.customerNumber , MAX(`counted`) FROM
(
SELECT customerNumber, COUNT(*) AS `counted`
FROM `orders`
GROUP BY `customerNumber`
)as maxCount
```

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 5):

Just use `ORDER BY` with your inner query:

```
SELECT customerNumber, COUNT(*) AS `counted`
FROM `orders`
GROUP BY `customerNumber`
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If you want to return *all* customer numbers in the event of a tie, you can use a `HAVING` clause with a subquery which identifies the maximum count:

```
SELECT customerNumber, COUNT(*) AS counted
FROM orders
GROUP BY customerNumber
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(t.counted) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS counted
                                               FROM orders
                                               GROUP BY customerNumber) t)
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: @onedaywhen I updated my answer to give the option to also return all customer numbers with the highest count.